# Changing str to int in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am trying to make a small elavator program.

The code:

```
import time
elavator = True
# 0 is B floor // basement
elavatorFloors = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

while elavator == True:
    getLevel = input ("Which floor would you like to visit? ( 1 - 5) ")
    time.sleep(2)
    print "you're now at floor, " +int.getLevel
```

I get this error: AttributeError: type object 'int' has no attribute 'getLevel'
Aside from changing the str to int, am I using any bad technique? I really want to improve my programming thinking and code writing. Thank you :)

Comment: Use `int(getLevel)`. And why are you not asking for level 0?

Comment: You're using `input`, so getLevel will already be an integer. That said, you should probably use `raw_input` and cast to an integer explicitly.

Comment: @Xymostech While the OP is using 2.x, it's worth noting that what you said only applies to older versions of Python. In 3.x, `input()` does not evaluate the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`int()` is a type, so to instantiate it, you need to do `int(getLevel)`, not `int.getLevel`.

Check [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) for examples and more.

Also note that `getLevel` is an odd name for the variable, as it implies it is a function that gives the level. A better name would be just `level`.

It's also worth noting that `input()` evaluates the input as Python code (In Python 2.x, in 3.x it acts as `raw_input()` does in older versions), so `getLevel` will already be a number, although I would recommend using `raw_input()` instead, and keeping your conversion from a string to an integer, as it won't allow arbitrary execution of code, which is much better.

Comment: Thank you. it works, but more importantly I get it with your explanation. I have to practice to become fluent. I appreciate the advice also regarding level vs getLevel :)

Answer (score -2):

Here is the sample code modified:

```
import time
elevator = "false"
# 0 is B floor // basement
elavatorFloors = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
getLevel = input("Which floor would you like to visit? ( 1 - 5) ")
for x in elavatorFloors:
    if x == getLevel:
        time.sleep(getLevel)
        print "you're now at floor, " + str(getLevel)
        elevator = "true"
        pass
    else:
        pass
if (elevator == "false"):
    print "There is no floor: " +  str(getLevel)
```